# In jquery string I want to pass filed value instead of constant as parameter

Tags: jquery, string, url, hyperlink, reverse

In below string I using constant 1 but here I want to use item1.id as each parameter. Please help to construct the string. I tried all the way up to here but not able to insert item1.id instead of 1. Now by clicking hyperline it goes to book.id =1 only

```
 success: function (books) {
            console.log(books);
            html=""
            $.each(books, function(index, item) {
                $.each(item, function(index1, item1) {
                    console.log(item1.id);
                     html += "<tr> <td> <a href= '{% url 'select_stock_report' *** 1 *** %}'>"+item1.code+" 
    </a></td> " +
                         " html +=  <td>" + item1.code + "</td> <td>" + item1.name + "</td>" + 
    item1.open_qty + " </td>" +
                         "<td>" + item1.recived_qty + " </td>  <td>" + item1.return_qty + " </td>" +
                         " <td>" + item1.issue_qty + " </td> <td>" + item1.adj_qty + "</td> <td>" + 
    item1.bal_qty + "</td></tr>"
                });
              })
                $('#stock_list tbody').html(html); //add datas inside tbody} })})}
        }
```

Comment: You can't evaluate that expression the way you would like. That is server side code that runs in a completely different environment and at a different time. You can't mix languages that way. Also note you added a number of meaningless tags to the question but not any tag relating to language/framework for `{% url '...' %}`

Comment: Hi, just use generated url from `'{% url 'select_stock_report'..%}` then just replace that `1` to your `item1.id`.

Comment: if i replace 1 with item1.id i am getting error when loading page itself as:NoReverseMatch at /stock_report
Reverse for 'select_stock_report' with arguments '('',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['listselectstktrans/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', 'wstore/listselectstktrans/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']

Comment: 1 means item1.id value of first record in $.each statement; so I want item1.id  from loop replacing the number 1